# In PHP Is there a way to determine the first time a value is used in a while loop?

Tags: php, while-loop, iteration

I have a while loop where I am returning departments. I want to be able to determine if it is the first time a department is returned. The code is as follows:

```
$myArray = array('Finance', 'Marketing', 'Customer Service', 'Marketing', 'Marketing', 'IT', 'Finance', 'IT');
while(list ($key, $val) = each ($myArray))
{
    echo $val . "<br />";
}
```

The above code outputs the below:

Finance

Marketing

Customer Service

Marketing

Marketing

IT

Finance

IT

Is there a way where I can have it output the following?:

Finance(first)

Marketing(first)

Customer Service(first)

Marketing

Marketing

IT(first)

Finance

IT

Answer (score 1):

I think you will have to keep track of used values manually:

```
<?php
$used = [];

foreach ($myArray as $department) {
    if (isset($used[$department])) {
        // The key exists, it means it's been used already
        echo $department . '<br />';
    } else {
        // The key doesn't exist; we're using it for the first time
        echo $department . ' (first)<br />';
        // Add the key with a true value
        $used[$department] = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: To @aconnelly that suggested the edit, `empty($used[$department])` won't trigger any invalid index error. In fact you can use empty with unexisting arrays and unexisting indexes and nothing will happen. The only difference between isset and empty is that isset means "is not null" while empty means "is not equivalent to null" (i.e. empty strings, false, 0, etc). However, `isset` reads more naturally in this case as "if key is set..." instead of "if key is not empty...".

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$varList[0]['value'] = 'Finance';
$varList[1]['value'] = 'Marketing';
$varList[2]['value'] = 'Customer Service';


for ($i=0;$i<count($varList);$i++) {
    if ($varList[$i]['lastUsed'] == '') {
        $varList[$i]['lastUsed'] = $now;

        echo "{$varList[$i]['value']} (first time being used)";
    } else {
        echo "{$varList[$i]['value']} was last used {$varList[$i]['lastUsed']}";
    }
}
```

Comment: if $varList has a million items you run count a million times, you only need it once

Comment: No scope was provided on WHAT is being accomplished or how often. I merely provided HOW to make it work, best practices are for him to figure out :)

Comment: Your usage of string interpolation here is dangerous.  You're outputting arbitrary data in the context of HTML.  You should be using `htmlspecialchars()`.

Comment: No, i'm showing him how to iterate through values and providing him with a debugging medium. It's not up to me to solve every detail for him, i'm here to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Using a whileloop and check within the loop that will be made every_single_iteration using the following:-

```
$myArray = array('Finance', 'Marketing', 'Customer Service', 'Marketing', 'Marketing', 'IT', 'Finance', 'IT');
$numItems = count($myArray);
$i=0;
$firstitem=$myArray[0];
$i++;
while($i<$numItems-1){
    $some_item=$myArray[$i];
    $i++;
}
$last_item=$myArray[$i];
$i++;
```

or

```
$myArray = array('Finance', 'Marketing', 'Customer Service', 'Marketing', 'Marketing', 'IT', 'Finance', 'IT');
$keys = array_keys($myArray);
$numItems = count($keys);
$i=0;
$firstItem=$myArray[$keys[0]];
# Special handling of the first item goes here
$i++;
while($i<$numItems-1){
    $item=$myArray[$keys[$i]];
    # Handling of regular items
    $i++;
}
$lastItem=$myArray[$keys[$i]];
# Special handling of the last item goes here
$i++;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this: (short and sweet)

```
<?php

    $myArray = array('Finance', 'Marketing', 'Customer Service', 'Marketing',
'Marketing', 'IT', 'Finance', 'IT');
    while(list ($key, $val) = each ($myArray))
    {
        echo $val .(isset($t[$val]) ? '' : $t[$val] = '(first)').'<br/>';
    }
```

So, all you need to do is to add `.(isset($t[$val]) ? '' : $t[$val] = '(first)').` with your echo within your existing code.

Comment: This works perfectly when I try it with a known array length. Can I do this if the while loop is looping through SQL records?

Comment: @sjw0525 yes it should work with sql query results, I dont see why it wont

Answer (score 0):

I you want it to be with a while loop, I guess you could try something like this

```
$myArray = array('Finance', 'Marketing', 'Customer Service', 'Marketing', 'Marketing', 'IT', 'Finance', 'IT');
$used = [];
$numItems = count($myArray);
$i=0;
while($i<$numItems){
    if (isset($used[$department])) {
        echo $department;
    } else {
        echo $department . ' (first)';
        $used[$department] = true;
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Personally I would use a foreach like @Parziphal suggested